# Formatting an ext4 partition with a 16KB block, possible?

Tags: format, ext4

I've been looking all over for this. I need to format a 6TB drive I have with a 16KB AUS in order to achieve maximum dedup.
Is this possible?

I tried this with mkfs and got the following warning:

```
mkfs.ext4: 16384-byte blocks too big for system (max 4096)
Proceed anyway? (y,n) n
```

Is it suppose to be safe?

Comment: Probably of interest: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73568/70524

Answer (score 9):

You need to use mkfs.ext4 with `-C 16384` and also `-O  bigalloc`. From `man mkfs.ext4`:

> **-C cluster-size**
>   Specify the size of cluster in bytes for filesystems using the
>   bigalloc feature.  Valid cluster-size values are from 2048 to 256M
>   bytes per cluster.  This can only be specified if  the  bigalloc 
>   feature  is  enabled. (See the ext4 (5) man page for more details
>   about bigalloc.) The default cluster size if bigalloc is enabled is 16
>   times the block size.

The *default* cluster size would be 64KiB (16x4) if using 4096 byte blocks, as found in `/etc/mke2fs.conf`. This only applies if `bigalloc` is enabled at all; otherwise the cluster size is the block size.

Depending on the number of files you expect, you may also wish to set `-i inode_ratio`. The default is 16KiB+ on most systems, so you won't run out; but it may be inefficient if the average file is much larger.

The version of ext4 in your system's kernel must support the `bigalloc` feature, [added in Linux 3.2](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Bigalloc).

Comment: this should be marked as correct answer

Comment: Here is a reference to Bigalloc from Linux Kernel Wiki: https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Bigalloc

Answer (score 0):

According to `man mkfs.ext4`,

```
OPTIONS
       -b block-size
              Specify  the  size  of blocks in bytes.  Valid block-size values
              are 1024, 2048 and 4096 bytes per block.  If omitted, block-size
              is  heuristically  determined  by  the  filesystem  size and the
              expected usage of the filesystem (see the -T option).  If block-
              size  is preceded by a negative sign ('-'), then mke2fs will use
              heuristics to determine the appropriate  block  size,  with  the
              constraint  that  the  block  size  will  be at least block-size
              bytes.  This  is  useful  for  certain  hardware  devices  which
              require that the blocksize be a multiple of 2k.
```

It seems to me that only block-size values 1024, 2048 and 4096 bytes are valid, but maybe these values are only examples. You can try with the option

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -b 16384 /dev/sdxn
```

where x is the drive letter and n is the partition number. I tested in 16.04 with the xenial kernel (linux 4.4 series), and `mkfs.ext4` complained

```
mkfs.ext4: 16384-byte blocks too big for system (max 4096)
Proceed anyway? (y,n)
```

I continued to create the file system, but could not mount it because of errors, so the answer is *No, it does not work*, unless you mount it with some special method.

Comment: well, I eventually found out I need to re-compile the kernel in order to use 16k blocks.

Comment: @JustAGuy, Is it a feasible option for you to re-compile the kernel?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: @JustAGuy, Would a `FAT` file system work for your application, and in that case, would sector size = 16384 serve the purpose you wanted to implement with `ext4`? According to `man mkfs.vfat` you can try the option `-S 16384`; at least you can test the performance of such a file system for a huge partition.